# Are pointers stored in std::set const?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, set, constants

I'm hunting a bug in code and I have a problem:

```
 class a
 {
 public:
 void foo(int a) {}
 }

  std::set<a*> set;
  std::set<a*>::iterator it = set.begin();

  it->foo(55); //gives me error:
  // error: request for member ‘foo’ in ‘* it.std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator-><a*>()’, which is of pointer type ‘a* const’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
```

Why it doesn't allow me to use non-const function on it? What can I do to have a set of non-const pointers without using casting?

Comment: The iterator returns you a const reference, because you are not allowed to modify the value it refers to (since it is used as the key into the `std::set`). But that's not your problem here.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker yes, it's not the problem. with double dereference everything works.

Comment: By the way: the pointers stored in an `std::set` **are** `const`. But they are not pointers **to** `const`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to dereference *twice*:

```
(*it)->foo(55);
```

– `it` is an iterator to a pointer. Your code would be correct if you had an `std::set<a>` instead of an `std::set<a*>`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is you need to deference the iterator and then the pointer. replace `it->foo(55);` with `(*it)->foo(55);` This will work.

Answer (score 2):

You're one level of indirection out.

```
(*it)->foo(55);
```

works, as `it` is effectively a pointer to the type stored, which is itself a pointer.